# How to correctly use setStyle on a geojson with leaftlet 1.6.0?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet 1.6.0. I want to regurlarly change the color of a geojson which should be done, if not mistaken, with `setStyle`.

To achieve this, I use an interval, like the following:

```js
        geo_json = L.geoJSON(geo, {
            style: {
                stroke: true,
                color: "black",
                fillColor: "blue"
            }
        }).addTo(map);
        function high(obj) {
            const current_color = obj.options.style.color
            console.log(obj.options.style)
            if (current_color == "black") {
                console.log("to blue")
                obj.setStyle({
                    color: "blue",
                    fillColor: "yellow",
                    stroke: true
                })
            } else {
                console.log("to black")
                obj.setStyle({
                    color: "black",
                    fillColor: "back",
                    stroke: true
                })
            }
        }
        var inter = setInterval(high, 100, geo_json)
```

However, this does not work.

When going through the `high` function the first time, the color is correcly set. But during the next iterations, the value of obj.options.style.color is still at "black". As a consequence, it never goes from blue to black again. It **seems** like the `setStyle` is not affecing object properties even though it changes its color.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkvhy4wf/1/).

How should I properly use `setStyle` to regurlarly update the color of my geojson ?

Comment: Just for reference, this is indeed expected behaviour, and it _might_ actually suit your case: by updating only the child layers style, the GeoJSON Layer Group style remains at its initial value, which enables using [`resetStyle()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-resetstyle) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the function `setStyle` of L.GeoJOSN only changes the style of the child layers and not of it self:

```
    setStyle: function (style) {
        return this.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            this._setLayerStyle(layer, style);
        }, this);
    },
```

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/d6d6051ac6acbc2c68b6b0f8ef1707cf91054f16/src/layer/GeoJSON.js#L148

If you want to change the style option of the GeoJSON layer you need to update the property manually:

```
var newStyle = {
   color: "black",
   fillColor: "back",
   stroke: true
};

obj.setStyle(newStyle);
obj.options.style = Object.assign({}, obj.options.style, newStyle); // merge the new style into the old one
```